Trying to find quote about urge to buy a new blank notebook
I have this quote written down in a story I'm editing, but the writer cannot remember where they got it from:

None but a fellow poet might understand the urge to buy a new notebook,
even if there may be ten blank ones lying at home.

They can't even remember if this is a real quote or one that they made up, because this is something that was written years ago that they have recently repurposed.
So - does anyone know this quote or a similar one? I tried Googling, but only got hits for Shakespeare, which I have not told the writer about as they already have a sufficiently high opinion of themselves.

I have seen similar comments often posted in memes about writers, but I don't have an actual source.
